# Font smoothing not working on Mac Mini

Tags: display, mac-mini, font, resolution, displayport

I purchased a new Mac Mini and have attempted to hook it up to my [ASUS VS278Q-P](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009HNEBLK) LCD Monitor. I was using this monitor in Windows and it looked fine but on the mac mini, it's having a problem where the font display is really blurry. It seems this is a bit of a common problem and others have fixed it by changing the font smoothing. This, of course, didn't work for me:

`defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int 0` (..and 1 - 4 as well)

I've also tried three different cables with no change:

- Mini DisplayPort <> DisplayPort
- HDMI <> HDMI
- Mini DisplayPort + VGA converter <> VGA

I've tried to capture the worst fonts using "zoom" feature (pic below). Notice the "t" and "i" characters are mostly crisp while others like the "l" characters are blurry.

Have also fiddled with different settings on the monitor trying to get rid of it but basically just made things worse. Any ideas how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that **is** smoothed. The issue is the low resolution for such a large monitor - see http://www.techradar.com/reviews/pc-mac/monitors-and-projectors/monitors/asus-vs278q-1120824/review for some unhappy opinion.

Comment: Monitor #2 is Dell P2715Q. Much better, but refresh maxes out at 30Hz. Apparently a limitation of the mac mini not supporting 60Hz refresh :/  (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202856), (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6605359?tstart=0).  FWIW however, the font on the Dell is much, much better than the Asus.